# code missing values for many/all variables at once

Tags: spss

Suppose i have such table
[image]

if i use syntax to indicate missing values for variables, i must for each variable write something like

```
if missing (s1) s1=999.
MISSING VALUES s1 (999).
exe

if missing (s20) s20=999.
MISSING VALUES s20 (999).
exe
```

and so on.

but if i have 100 variables it will long and difficult.
is it possible to inditace missing values at once for all vars in my data
something like?

```
   if missing (s1-q35) s1-q35=999.



   MISSING VALUES s1-q35 (999).
    exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `recode` like this:

```
recode s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 .... q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 ..... (miss=999).
```

If some of your variables are consecutive in the data you can use "`to`". For example:

```
recode s1 to s21 q1 to q35 (miss=999).
```

If they are all consecutive you can use to for all of them:

```
missing values s1 to q35 (999).
```